# Read_Csv() not giving expected output ,After If i update any cell in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

1) Creation of DF

```
import pandas as pd
li=[["10","Data","String","01249","0199"],["10","Data","String","",""]]
df=pd.DataFrame(li)
df.to_csv("Dummy.csv")
```

2)Dummy.csv Looks like

```
   0   1     2     3   4
0 10 Data String 1249 199
1 10 Data String
```

3) Tested this piece of code for clarification:

```
D=pd.read_csv(Dummy.csv,dtype=str)
print(D['3'])
```

Gave Expected output:

```
0  01249
1   NAN
```

**4) I need to manually fill the empty cell in the 3rd and 4th column with value in before cell here say "01249" and "0199" by opening the csv in a excel.**Successfully changed and saved the Dummy.csv in excel.**

5) So again i have validation.py file will open the dummy.csv to validate.So to read the csv and further process by following code same as 3rd step.

```
D=pd.read_csv(Dummy.csv,dtype=str)
print(D['3'])
```

Its not my expected output:

```
0  1249
1  1249
```

My expected output is:

```
0  01249
1  01249
```

So it is some serious issue i cannot omit that leading zeros at front. you all can see that if i not edit that column in csv and tried to read with read_csv giving expected output in string dtype,If i update the cell with "01249" in csv,and tried to read with read_csv not giving expected output in same string dtype. I think excel changing that total column datatype to **General**, I doesn't what general means.

**So at end, After updating the cells in csv also i need to get my expected output please, How can i do this.**

Sorry for the long body, i need to clearly explain my all steps i have tried.

Comment: Excel will interpret the strings as numbers, and remove the leading zero.

Comment: Yeah correct,So tell me how can i avoid that while reading with read_csv().this is the main functionality in m code because this leading total production is stopped.Is anyother way is there to instead read_csv??@Stefan

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. Is this an Excel question or a Python question? If you need to use Excel, you should be careful to format the columns as text (but Excel will insist on converting to numbers, if it get the chance ). If you have rule for when there should be a leading zero, you could restore it in the Python code.

Comment: Where, in the process you show, are you using Excel? If you are not using Excel in this process you should not use the Excel tag.

Comment: @Stefan Sorry for the unclear question Primarily this is excel problem.So suggest me if this is scenario how can i avoid this.What do you mean by restoring it in the python code?

Comment: @SolarMike Removed the tag and sorry about that

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to change it manually? Can't you just added it in python?

Answer (score 0):

It is an Excel issue as opposed to python.

Change the type of the whole column (by clicking on the column letter) to **text** instead of general.
General means that you are allowing Excel to guess the datatype, and since these are numbers it omits the leading zero.